# Property 'XXXX' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have one component where I use `useHistory` to move to another component on a button click. This is the code till now:

***Component1.tsx***

```
 let history = useHistory();

 const someEventHandler = event => {
    history.push({
        pathname: '/Comp2',
        search: '?flow=abc',
        state: { detail: 'some_value' }
    });
 };

...
<Button onClick={someEventHandler}>Submit</Button>
```

***Component2.tsx***

```
const location = useLocation();
useEffect(
    () => {
        console.log(location.pathname);
        console.log((location.state).detail); <-- Error here
    }
)
```

The button is getting redirected with the correct path and queryParams. But I am unable to get the details part that I am sending in from the first component.

And I am getting the following error:

```
any
Property 'details' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(2339)
```

I am sending in the props correctly, but still not able to receive the data(details) part from the `useLocation`. Can we get this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/navigation.md):

```js
history.push({
  pathname: '/home',
  search: '?the=query'
}, {
  some: state
});
```

You need to define the state in a separate object

Also when used with typescript you need to tell it what your might be state looks like e.g.

```js
const location = useLocation<{ details: string | undefined }>()
```

Otherwise you will get a typescript compile error

Comment: I have tried this approach from the docs:
`history.push('/home?the=query', { some: 'state' });` But still getting the same error.

Comment: @SharathKamlekar See my updated answer. You might be getting a typescript error but for future reference you really should mention the usage of typescript and if the error comes from the console or from terminal during compile process